# How to calculate the "at least once" probability of an event in continuous time with time dependent probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, limits, conditional-probability

I have an event $E$ that happens in some small timestep $\delta t$ with probability $\delta p(t')=\delta t\alpha(t')$. I'm trying to figure out the probability that the event happens at least once from $t'=0$ to $t'=T$.

I know that if $\alpha$ were time independent, then I would just look for the product of probabilities that $E$ does *not* happen at each timestep, i.e.
\begin{equation}
P_\text{at least once}(T)=1-\lim_{\delta t \to0}\left(1-\delta t\alpha\right)^{T/\delta t}=1-e^{-\alpha T}
\end{equation}
But when $\alpha$ has time dependence I don't have an exponent of $T/\delta t$ in my limit, I just have a product of $1-\delta p(t')$ at different timesteps, with different $\delta p(t')$s.

Am I missing some really basic way to do this? I have $\alpha(t')$ explicitly, but it's very ugly in the problem I'm studying, so I'm looking to see if there's a general solution for an arbitrary $\alpha(t')$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So like a Poisson process with the rate $\alpha$ of occurrence varing with time, and a result like $1-\exp\left(-\int_{t'=0}^T \alpha\, dt'\right)$ which reduces to $1-\exp\left(-\alpha T\right)$ when $\alpha$ is constant?

Comment: @Henry Yes! I guess I hadn't realized this is just a Poisson process with time dependent rate. How did you get that the time integral just appears in the exponent like that?

Comment: The probability of at least one event occurring in $[0,T]$ is one minus the probability of zero events occurring in $[0,T]$.

Comment: @AndrewForbes Assuming $\alpha$ is reasonably well behaved, an approach similar to Riemann integrals will get you there: take the limit of the combination of intervals each with constant rates.